# Selecting a row with the greater serial number

Tags: sql

so I have a sql table which includes rows with serial numbers. Now I need to select only one row, and it should be the one with the largest serial number.

Ex

```
17 Cool Dude
18 Riha
```

I need to select the row "18 Riha" ....how do i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember to specify *which* SQL implementation of SQL you're talking about (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY serial DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL you can use the TOP keyword.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table ORDER BY serial DESC
```

Comment: i need to select the entire row with its data. can u give me the code for it. thanks.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table ORDER BY serial DESC` Updated answer to match.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT : Oracle-Specific***

Get the maximum serial number and then get the row/rows (if the max serial number is not unique) that has/have the serial number.

```
select * from table1
where id = (select max(id) from table1);
```

Or order the results by ID descending and then get the first row in the result set..

```
select * from (
select * from table1
order by id desc)
where rownum = 1
```

or Use analytic functions...

```
select * from 
(select t1.*, rank () over (order by t1.id desc) rnk
  from table1 t1
) where rnk = 1;
```